# Establishing a TCP Session without terminating it (not sending RST/FIN)

Tags: linux, tcp, software-rec

I'm looking for information for a project. I'm looking for a Linux tool which can just establish a TCP session and leave at it there without sending a FIN/RST.

I tried tools like `iperf` etc., which sends out a FIN as well once the connection is established.

Kindly let me know if there are any tools that are available?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The kernel manages the SYN/FIN/RST as part of the TCP protocol, so there are no tools *as such* that create a TCP stream without ending it.

Some possibilities

- Write your own code that generates the raw SYN and SYN/ACK packets directly
- Use a standard tool but just leave it suspended until it's no longer required

  ```
  nc remoteHost remotePort &    # nc example.com 80
  ncPID=$!

  sleep 1
  kill -STOP $ncPID
  ```
- Use a standard tool and implement a firewall rule to block the stream before closing it

  ```
  nc remoteHost remotePort &
  ncPID=$!

  sleep 1
  iptables -I OUTPUT --dst remoteHost --dport remotePort -j DROP
  kill $ncPID

  sleep 1
  iptables -D OUTPUT --dst remoteHost --dport remotePort -j DROP
  ```